# reading errors returned from psql in a bash script

Tags: bash, postgresql, psql

I need to check for errors when running psql from a bash script.  Here's an example of how we're running things in the script:

```
return_value=$(psql \
-X \
 $POSTGRES_CONNECTION_STRING \
-f ./build_table.sql \
-w \
-b \
-A \
-q \
-t \
)

psql_exit_status=$?
```

The above statement works fine *unless* there's an error in the sql script, in which case I get some error output on the console but `return_value` is set to zero, as is `psql_exit_status`.

The `build_table` sql script creates a table and imports data from a csv file-- if there are errors in the csv file, or if, say, I intentionally misspell  `create tableeeee` in the sql script I see psql errors on the screen but no error info is returned as best I can tell.

I've tried using the `-o` flag in psql to output to a file.  Nothing shows, it's a blank file.  I've also tried adding a `2>&1` bit after the psql statement to see if I could get some error info that way, but nothing doing.

What I need is some way to tell that the sql script has exited abnormally and/or crashed, without having to look at the output on the screen.  Is that possible with the way I'm executing psql?  Possible something's up with one of my psql flags?

Comment: I don't know `psql`, but its man page suggests you may need to enable `ON_ERROR_STOP` for it to exit with error in such cases.

Answer (score 6):

From the [`psql` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html):

> psql returns 0 to the shell if it finished normally, 1 if a fatal error of its own occurs (e.g. out of memory, file not found), 2 if the connection to the server went bad and the session was not interactive, and 3 if an error occurred in a script and the variable `ON_ERROR_STOP` was set.

So you need to add `-v ON_ERROR_STOP=on` to your `psql` options.

However setting this variable has the following side effect:

> By default, command processing continues after an error. When this variable is set to on, processing will instead stop immediately. In interactive mode, psql will return to the command prompt; otherwise, psql will exit, returning error code 3 to distinguish this case from fatal error conditions, which are reported using error code 1. In either case, any currently running scripts (the top-level script, if any, and any other scripts which it may have in invoked) will be terminated immediately. If the top-level command string contained multiple SQL commands, processing will stop with the current command.

Comment: Sorry, I had to fix your answer. `ON_ERROR_STOP` is not an environment variable.

Comment: This is really weird.  Your suggestion definitely sounds like the way to go, however when I add it to my psql options, and the sql script fails, my entire bash script quits at that point too-- I've output some `echo` comands directly after calling psql with `-v ON_ERROR_STOP=on`, and they're never reached. 
 As a result I have no opportunity to check the return value from psql.

Comment: @steve sure thing, I put a description of it in another SO post regarding the exit issues here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58965726/psql-return-value-error-killing-the-shell-script-that-called-it