# psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 not working, cannot terminate script execution

Tags: database, postgresql, psql

I have a bash script that calls another script containing a psql command, i want to stop executing when the psql command fails. The below psql call is to execute a postgres function.
In below script the echo $exitcode always returns 0 even if script calling postgres function returns a error. I want psql command to return right error code, so i can handle it properly in below script.
FirstScript:

```
list=`sh /opt/dbb_promo_list.sh -60 -30`
ID_LIST=`echo $list |sed 's/[a-z _-]*//g'|sed 's/(.*//g'`

exitcode=$? 
echo $exitcode //always returns 0 both in successful and error case, i want it to return corresponding exit code for error, so i can handle it and stop the script.
if [ $exitcode -ne 0 ] ; then
  echo "There seems to have errors while running script "
  echo "Exit code is : "$exitcode
  exit 1
fi
```

dbb_promo_list.sh : This script contains the following command

```
psql -U $DB_USERNAME -h $DB_HOST -p $DB_PORT -d $DATABASE -c "SELECT schema.${PROCEDURE}($day_begin,$day_end)"
```

Error thrown below when calling the above command. Since this error is thrown the psql command shouldnt return exit code 0 but its not the case, it returns 0 even if the postgres function works fine or returns a error like below. I am not sure if there a way to tweak in bash script to recognize a error is thrown

```
ERROR:  function string_agg(numeric, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT string_agg(pmotn_id, ',')               FROM ppcapr.p...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

When the sql function fails. It then reports the error on the console, but continues to proceed with executing remainder of the script. But i want the script execution to terminate once the error occurs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `ON_ERROR_STOP` is only going to cause `psql` to exit per "In interactive mode, psql will return to the command prompt; otherwise, psql will exit, returning error code 3 ...". It has nothing to do with the `Bash` script.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver as per this response, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58944395/reading-errors-returned-from-psql-in-a-bash-script it should work with bash script also. I just want to do some exception handling to stop script execution, when there is a error thrown from the sql file that is being called

Comment: See the follow up answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58965726/psql-return-value-error-killing-the-shell-script-that-called-it).  In particular "ON_ERROR_STOP will not work with the -c option. ...".

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks for that, i didnt see that. I also tried to capture the response of psql into a variable, as per this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242752/store-postgresql-result-in-bash-variable , but it doesnt reach my echo variable statement , after psql command is run

Comment: Update your question with the revised code.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver  I have made some edits, i hope it explains my scenario properly. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `$?` variable holds the last executed command exit code.

In your code, the last command executed before the `exitcode=$?` line is `sed 's/(.*//g'`, not the psql command. Just moving up this line may solve the issue.

P.S.: I see it's an old question, but someone may benefit from the answer.